# Oracle Trigger-facing ORA-01403 no data found

Tags: oracle

I am creating a trigger on insert or update statement in oracle.

I want to update `table2` with refer of table1

Please refer the below:

```
select aa,bb,cc 
  from table2 
 where loid in(select loid 
                 from table1 
                where eqid = :new.eqid)
```

After fetching records of `aa`, `bb` and `cc`, I have to update these fields for the other `loid` with the refer of these fetched `aa`, `bb` and `cc` values

```
update table2 
   set aa = aa, 
       bb = bb, 
       cc = cc
 where loid in (select loid 
                  from table1 
                 where masterid = eqid)
```

but when I'm trying to do this, I'm getting

> ORA-01403 no data found

error.

Could you please help me here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you will also get a mutating trigger because you are selecting from the same table as the trigger operates on.  What is wrong with a simple update statement?

Comment: Now I am using below statement to update the child records:   update table2 set (aa,bb,cc) =
(select aa,bb,cc from table2 where loid in
(select loid  from table1 where masterflag = 1 and eqid = :new.eqid))
where loid in 
(select loid from table1 where mastereqid = :new.eqid); BUt data is not getting updated in table2. Please help me here...

Comment: run just the select part to see what values are being returned.  and dont forget to commit.